# appending tuple of values to list in kafka consumer data

Tags: python, flask, apache-kafka

I have a kafka consumer which consumes 5000 data per second
Im receving the producer data in this format

```
producer sent data  ['UUTO9QJ', (14, 77, 'bike', "{'lat': 14, 'long': 77, 'elevation': 900, 
'bearing': 67, 'device': 'bike', 'batt_temp': 99, 'batt_voltage': 11.98, 'type': 'v1', 
'device_id': 'JHVJ5HGJD'}")]
```

I have folllowing code:

```
@kafkaBus.handle('topic')
def logic_of_data(msg):
    # kafkaBus = kafkaBus.run()
    print(f" Consumer recivied  data  {msg}")
    # print(ConsumerRecord[7])
    l = msg.value
    print(l[0])# l[0] holds this values UUTO9QJ
    val = tuple(l[1])  # holds this value (13, 77, 'bike', "{'lat': 13, 'long': 77, 'elevation': 
    # 900, 'bearing': 67, 'device': 'bike', 'batt_temp': 99, 'batt_voltage': 11.98, 'type': 'v1', 
    # 'device_id': 'JHVJ5HGJD'}")
    print(val, type(val))
    datalist.append(val)
    print(datalist,len(datalist))
```

```
datalist = []
tablefields = ['device_id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'jsonval'] 

if len(datalist) == 5000:
    print("Threshold reached")
    if val := checktableExists(cur, conn, l[0]):
        print("started procrssing")
        Insertval(cur, l[0], tablefields, datalist, conn)
        del datalist[:]
    else:
        print("create new table")
        createtable(cur, conn, l[0])
        Insertval(cur, l[0], tablefields, datalist, conn)
        del datalist[:]
```

the value till 3 records are appened are coming correctly as of statement     print(datalist,len(datalist))

```
[(12, 77, 'bike', "{'lat': 12, 'long': 77, 'elevation': 900, 'bearing': 67, 'device': 
'bike', 'batt_temp': 99, 'batt_voltage': 11.98, 'type': 'v1', 'device_id': 'JHVJ5HGJD'}"), 
(13, 77, 'bike', "{'lat': 13, 'long': 77, 'elevation': 900, 'bearing': 67, 'device': 'bike', 
'batt_temp': 99, 'batt_voltage': 11.98, 'type': 'v1', 'device_id': 'JHVJ5HGJD'}"), (14, 77, 
'bike', "{'lat': 14, 'long': 77, 'elevation': 900, 'bearing': 67, 'device': 'bike', 
'batt_temp': 99, 'batt_voltage': 11.98, 'type': 'v1', 'device_id': 'JHVJ5HGJD'}")] 
 3
```

After that the count becomes 1

```
[(15, 77, 'bike', "{'lat': 15, 'long': 77, 'elevation': 900, 'bearing': 67, 'device': 
'bike', 'batt_temp': 99, 'batt_voltage': 11.98, 'type': 'v1', 'device_id': 'JHVJ5HGJD'}")] 1
```

I want something that gives list with 5000 tuples of value l[1] in it. How can it be done

Comment: How many partitions are in your topic? How many instances of this code are you using? This isn't very scalable as you can only run one of these to bring all data together

Comment: Also, looks like you're doing something with tables... Why not use Kafka Connect for that?

Comment: i am using 2 instances and 1 partition

Comment: since i have two threads , list is intialized twice , so some of the data is getting in one and some in another. what can i do for this

Comment: Only one instance can read from a partition at once. Therefore, the other list will always be empty. Also, what library are you using for this `@kafkaBus` annotation?

Comment: Flask-kafka is the library used. I have consumer class with all propertiies

Comment: Can you please share those properties in the question? And show what is being printed out as you get new messages